# sed command to remove in special character with string

Tags: unix, sed

I have string as **WEB-INF/lib/abc.jar**
This has to be removed via usage of sed command and output has to be **abc.jar**

**Input** : WEB-INF/lib/abc.jar

**Output**: abc.jar

I am trying the command separately as

```
sed 's/WEB-INF//g' | sed 's/lib//g'
```

However this has to be done in one shot not to be used in different commands .

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's~[^.]*/~~' input_file
abc.jar
```